# else mysql query to take up the first 20 dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query which has an `if..else` function. if the submit button is clicked, it will perform the particular query. else, the query will take in the first 20 dates in my database. however, i am not sure how to do the else query statement to take up only the first 20 dates. do help, thank you :)

```
<?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "sensors_database";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

            if(isset($_POST["usub"])){
            $date1 = $_POST["datepicker"];
            $date2 = $_POST["datepicker1"];


            $query1 = "SELECT time, Ultrasonic FROM pi_sensors_network WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'";

            $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
            {
                $dataset1[] = array(strtotime($row['time'])*1000,$row['Ultrasonic']);
                //echo strtotime($row['time'])*1000;
            }

        }

        else {



        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT `time`, `Ultrasonic` FROM `pi_sensors_network`   
WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: @Celine.Tan what does the error message say? I tested in my database, this query works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking between the dates you mentioned in the query, then use

```
limit
$query1 = "SELECT time, Ultrasonic FROM pi_sensors_network WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."' limit 0,20";
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create index on table < pi_sensors_network > on column < date >

```
    CREATE INDEX pi_sensors_network01 ON pi_sensors_network (`date`);
```

Then,

```
    SELECT 
            `time`,`Ultrasonic` 
    FROM 
            pi_sensors_network 
    WHERE 
            `date` IN ( SELECT `date` FROM 
                            (SELECT   DISTINCT(`date`)  
                             FROM     pi_sensors_network 
                             ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 0,20)
                         AS tmp ) ;
```

If your table is too large, This query may take long even after indexing, 
In this case, 
I'ld suggest you to make an array of first 20 dates by separate query and then implode it in your main query !

Comment: @Celine, If you will use LIMIT 20 in your main query, it will only give you first 20 records, not all the records of first 20 dates !  you will need to use SUBQUERY to fetch all records of  first 20 dates !  anyway, the choice is always yours !